# Quadric isomorphic to affine space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field and $X$ be irreducible in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}_K$. Prove, that $X$ is birationally isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{n}_K$ if and only if $X$ contains a point over $K$.

Actually, I can't prove the converse statement: if X is birationally isomorphis to nK then it contains a point over K. The direct statement is almost trivial.

Comment: This reads like you copied an exercise from a book (or an exam!) Can you explain what you have tried, where you are stuck, and so on?

Comment: @Asal Beag Dubh  This is not from an exam :) Actually, I can't prove the converse statement: if $X$ is birationally isomorphis to $\mathbb{A}_K^n$ then it contains a point over $K$. The direct statement is almost trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note: in the question statement, you don't specify that X is an irreducible quadric hypersurface.)

It's interesting that you found the converse harder. If two varieties $X$ and $Y$ are birational, then there are actually open dense subsets $U \subset X$ and $V \subset Y$ such that $U$ and $V$ are actually isomorphic (see for instance p.188 of http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf), any certainly any open dense subset of affine space contains $K$-rational points.

You imply that you already understand the other direction, but for completeness let me say that it's the usual trick of picking a rational point and projecting along it.

Comment: And the existence of $K$-rational point follows from the weak form of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. Am I right?

Comment: To see that rational points _exist_, you shouldn't need the Nullstellensatz. For instance, any n-tuple of numbers in $K$ constitutes a rational point of $\mathbb{A}^n$ (do you see why?). Though perhaps I was too careless - if $k$ is a finite field, then there can be open dense subsets with no rational points.